# Strange return onsubmit behaviour JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I have a form validaion script that is called by:

```
<form id="quote" name="quote" method="get"  onsubmit="return formvalidation();" action="#">
```

The HTML input:

```
<input id="sitesinput" name="sitesinput" maxlength="3" value="0" onChange='countAndRun()' />
```

This is part of the function, and works just fine, doesn't submit the form if the input is blank, zero etc:

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || x==0)
  {
  alert("You have not selected a total amount of sites.")
  return false;
  }
```

however if I add a couple of lines, to focus the window on the input and give it a red border, the form submits regardless of what is inputted:

```
  document.getElementByName("sitesinput").style.border="1px solid #F00"
  document.getElementByName("sitesinput").focus()
```

add into the function like this:

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].value;
if (x==null || x=="" || x==0)
  {
  alert("You have not selected a total amount of sites.")
  document.getElementByName("sitesinput").style.border="1px solid #F00"
  document.getElementByName("sitesinput").focus()
  return false;
  }
```

Thanks for looking.
B.

Comment: `document.getElementByName("sitesinput")`? I believe you're looking for `document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0]` unless you've added that function to `document`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the Javascript is failing somewhere. If there are JS errors because, for example, `.style` is `undefined`, your form will end up posting.

You'll also note that there's no `getElementByName()` method in Javascript but there is a `getElementsByName()` method (Elements, plural). This will be likely what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because this line is trying to put focus on more than one element?

```
  document.getElementByNames("sitesinput").focus()
```

You could try

```
 document.getElementByNames("sitesinput")[0].focus()
```

And as mentioned in the comments typo on the `getElementsByName` function

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would be:

```
var oInput = document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0];
var value = oInput.value;
if (value.length == 0)
{
    alert("You have not selected a total amount of sites.")
    oInput.style.border="1px solid #F00"
    oInput.focus()
    return false;
}
```

There's really no need to call `getElementsByName` over and over again.. call it once, store the element in local variable and use it. You might also improve your validation by making sure it's numeric and whole number:

```
if (value.length == 0 || isNaN(parseInt(value, 10)))
```

For the record, there was runtime error because `getElementsByName` returns array, and array has no `style` property or `focus` method - and upon error during `onsubmit`, the form will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
               var x=document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].value;
                             if (x==null || x=="" || x==0)
                              {
                              alert("You have not selected a total amount of sites.")
                              document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].style.border="1px solid #F00"
                              document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].focus()
                              return false;
                              }
```

- document.getElementsByName returns a array.
- There is no document.getElementByName
  in javascript ,this is  what causing the errors in your code.